# How to check due date is more than current date in javascript

Tags: javascript

This is my coding from javascript but it did't work

```
if ( $("#requestDueDate").val().length < CurDate ) {
    alert("Due date should be more than current date");
    setBoolean = false;
    return false; 
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: What format are your dates in?

Comment: dd/mm/yyyy - @stevemarvell

Comment: I'd investigate the date object.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/492994/compare-dates-with-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert the string to a date:

```
// Expect d/m/yyyy
function toDate(s) {
  s = s.split(/\D/g);
  return new Date(s[2],--s[1],s[0]);
}
```

Then compare to the current date:

```
function afterNow(s) {
  var now = new Date();
  return +toDate(s) > +now;
}
```

Try it:

```
afterNow('9/10/2013'); // false
afterNow('9/10/2031'); // true
```